# open IE browser and "connect" to existing IEDriverServer

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-iedriver

I'm running IEDriverServer as a different user.

```
RunAs("C:\\Exlporer/IEDriverServer.exe", "User","Password");
        _webdriverIE = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        var CustomerPage = new CRMLogin(_webdriverIE).GoToCRMURL("http://foo.com");

public void RunAs(string path, string username, string password)
{
    ProcessStartInfo myProcess = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
    myProcess.UserName = username;
    myProcess.Password = MakeSecureString(password);
    myProcess.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcess.LoadUserProfile = true;
    myProcess.Verb = "runas";
    myProcess.Domain = "DOM001";
    Process.Start(myProcess);
}

public SecureString MakeSecureString(string text)
{
    SecureString secure = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        secure.AppendChar(c);
    }

    return secure;
}
```

I would like to open the IE browser, but "connecting" it to the existing driver I just opened.

When calling to `InternetExplorerDriver`, it opens a new session of the driver (of course) and the previous one has no meaning in terms of recognize elements etc..

```
_webdriverIE = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

can I connect the browser to an existing `InternetExplorerDriver`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the trick.

```
  public static IWebDriver RunIEAsDifferentUser(string User,string Password)
    {
        RunAs("C:\\Exlporer/IEDriverServer.exe", User, Password);
        _webdriverIE = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:5555/"), DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
        return _webdriverIE;

    }
    public static void RunAs(string path, string username, string password)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo myProcess = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
        myProcess.UserName = username;
        myProcess.Password = MakeSecureString(password);
        myProcess.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess.LoadUserProfile = true;
        myProcess.Verb = "runas";
        myProcess.Domain = "DOM001";
        Process.Start(myProcess);
    }

    public static SecureString MakeSecureString(string text)
    {
        SecureString secure = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            secure.AppendChar(c);
        }

        return secure;
    }
```